# Adding multiple JTextFields under one ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am working with JTextFields, JComboBox, and buttons. When I select some information from JComboBox, I press the button. That creates a JTextField. and sets the text of the JTextField by using the getSelectedItem().toString() method.

The issue I am facing is that I want to 'add' multiple JTextFields as the user desires. So if user clicks the button 3 times, I want 3 new JTextFields. As of now, the JTextField gets overwrite.

```
        public AdjustmentForm() //constructor begins, method for embedded main class
        {


        setTitle("Other Therapy Options");
        setSize(620, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));


 String[] fluids = { "      ", "Normal Saline", "Albumin", "23.5% NaCl","3% NaCl", "pRBC"}; 
 String[] volume = { "      ", "30", "50", "100", "500", "1000", "other"};

fluidsList = new JComboBox(fluids); 
volumeList = new JComboBox(volume); 

...
...

        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
        }

            private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            setSize(620, 401);
            field1.setText(" "+fluidsList.getSelectedItem().toString()+", " +volumeList.getSelectedItem().toString() + " ml ");

        add(field1);

            }}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actionlistener just call container.add(new JtextField("Param"));

That will add multiple JTextfields. After that take care about your layout. I haven't worked with layouts for a while so I won't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where your problem is from the code you have provided.  However, if I take it at face value, it appears that your are reusing the field1 object rather than creating a new instance of JTextField upon every call to actionPerformed.  If you change the code to something similar to :

```
field1 = new JTextField();
field1.setText(...)
...
```

your code should work as expected.

Comment: then he will be left with one textfield recreated again and again

Comment: You wouldn't because the actionPerformed method already had the line of code: add(field1).  Regardless of where the field1 variable was maintained, the action of creating new textfield and adding it to the container will work as expected.

Comment: it's possible you need to invalidate the container. haven't tried tho.